# Powershell Correct Output Until It Gets Added to an HTML Report

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to edit a report that is emailed from our server on a schedule. I added the LogSize and Logsize2. I added it to the html report but when it gets emailed it comes back as "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo".
It works as intended when I run it without the rest of the report.

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {

$DiskInfo= Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object{$_.DriveType -eq 3} | Where-Object{ ($_.freespace/$_.Size)*100 -lt $thresholdspace} | 
Select-Object SystemName, DriveType, VolumeName, Name, @{n='Size (GB)';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.size/1gb)}}, @{n='FreeSpace (GB)';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/1gb)}}, @{n='PercentFree';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size*100)}} | ConvertTo-HTML -fragment



$LogSize= Get-ChildItem "C:\windows\logs\CBS\" -force -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum 
"{0:N2}" -f ($LogSize.sum/ 1mb) + "MB of CBS Logs" | out-string

$LogSize2= Get-ChildItem "C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.5337.5000.105\Data\Install\Logs\" -force -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum 
"{0:N2}" -f ($LogSize2.sum/ 1mb) + "MB of Symantec Logs" | out-string

#region System Info
$OS = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).caption
$SystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer | Select-Object Name, TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory
$TotalRAM = $SystemInfo.TotalVisibleMemorySize/1MB
$FreeRAM = $SystemInfo.FreePhysicalMemory/1MB
$UsedRAM = $TotalRAM - $FreeRAM
$RAMPercentFree = ($FreeRAM / $TotalRAM) * 100
$TotalRAM = [Math]::Round($TotalRAM, 2)
$FreeRAM = [Math]::Round($FreeRAM, 2)
$UsedRAM = [Math]::Round($UsedRAM, 2)
$RAMPercentFree = [Math]::Round($RAMPercentFree, 2)

#endregion

$TopProcesses = Get-Process -ComputerName $computer | Sort WS -Descending | Select ProcessName, Id, WS -First $ProccessNumToFetch | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#region Services Report
$ServicesReport = @()
$Services = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $computer | Where {($_.StartMode -eq "Auto") -and ($_.State -eq "Stopped")}

foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    $row = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $Service.Name
        Status = $Service.State
        StartMode = $Service.StartMode
    }

$ServicesReport += $row

}

$ServicesReport = $ServicesReport | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
#endregion

#region Event Logs Report
$SystemEventsReport = @()
$SystemEvents = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName System -EntryType Error,Warning -Newest $EventNum
foreach ($event in $SystemEvents) {
    $row = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        TimeGenerated = $event.TimeGenerated
        EntryType = $event.EntryType
        Source = $event.Source
        Message = $event.Message
    }
    $SystemEventsReport += $row
}

$SystemEventsReport = $SystemEventsReport | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

$ApplicationEventsReport = @()
$ApplicationEvents = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName Application -EntryType Error,Warning -Newest $EventNum
foreach ($event in $ApplicationEvents) {
    $row = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        TimeGenerated = $event.TimeGenerated
        EntryType = $event.EntryType
        Source = $event.Source
        Message = $event.Message
    }
    $ApplicationEventsReport += $row
}

$ApplicationEventsReport = $ApplicationEventsReport | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
#endregion

# Create the chart using our Chart Function
Create-PieChart -FileName ((Get-Location).Path + "\chart-$computer") $FreeRAM, $UsedRAM
$ListOfAttachments += "chart-$computer.png"
#region Uptime
# Fetch the Uptime of the current system using our Get-HostUptime Function.
$SystemUptime = Get-HostUptime -ComputerName $computer
#endregion

# Create HTML Report for the current System being looped through
$CurrentSystemHTML = @"
<hr noshade size=3 width="100%">
<div id="report">
<p><h2>$computer Report</p></h2>
<h3>System Info</h3>
<table class="list">
<tr>
<td>System Uptime</td>
<td>$SystemUptime</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>OS</td>
<td>$OS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total RAM (GB)</td>
<td>$TotalRAM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Free RAM (GB)</td>
<td>$FreeRAM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Percent free RAM</td>
<td>$RAMPercentFree</td>
</tr>
</table>

<IMG SRC="chart-$computer.png" ALT="$computer Chart">

<h3>Disk Info</h3>

<table class="normal">$DiskInfo</table>
<br></br>
<p>$LogSize</p>
<p>$LogSize2</p>

<br></br>

<div class="first column">
<h3>System Processes - Top $ProccessNumToFetch Highest Memory Usage</h3>
<p>The following $ProccessNumToFetch processes are those consuming the highest amount of Working Set (WS) Memory (bytes) on $computer</p>
<table class="normal">$TopProcesses</table>
</div>
<div class="second column">

<h3>System Services - Automatic Startup but not Running</h3>
<p>The following services are those which are set to Automatic startup type, yet are currently not running on $computer</p>
<table class="normal">
$ServicesReport
</table>
</div>

<h3>Events Report - The last $EventNum System/Application Log Events that were Warnings or Errors</h3>
<p>The following is a list of the last $EventNum <b>System log</b> events that had an Event Type of either Warning or Error on $computer</p>
<table class="normal">$SystemEventsReport</table>

<p>The following is a list of the last $EventNum <b>Application log</b> events that had an Event Type of either Warning or Error on $computer</p>
<table class="normal">$ApplicationEventsReport</table>
```

Comment: I've changed your code ever so slightly (functionally equivalent) just so the syntax highlighting works.

Answer (score 1):

put another one of these

```
$LogSize=
```

in front of this

```
"{0:N2}" -f ($LogSize.sum/ 1mb) + "MB of CBS Logs" | out-string
```

and do the same for LogSize2 so the end result could look like this

```
$LogSize= Get-ChildItem "C:\windows\logs\CBS\" -force -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum 
$LogSize= "{0:N2}" -f ($LogSize.sum/ 1mb) + "MB of CBS Logs" | out-string
$LogSize

$LogSize2= Get-ChildItem "C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.5337.5000.105\Data\Install\Logs\" -force -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum 
$LogSize2= "{0:N2}" -f ($LogSize2.sum/ 1mb) + "MB of Symantec Logs" | out-string
$LogSize2
```

Comment: Thank you! That works, but I don't understand how this is functionally different from what I had originally. What would cause it to work when I run just the snippet and not the entire report?

Comment: it looked fine because you were just outputting it to the console but not changing the value of the $LogSize variable. this way, the desired output is first assigned to the variable, then you just write its contents to the console window, but you can use it later in your script as well with the correct content.